# Can I send key press inputs from Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, ivr, amazon-connect, dtmf

I am using Amazon Connect but not in its usual capabilities. Instead of acting as an IVR, I am calling an IVR from Amazon Connect and follow the instructions. Is there any way that I can automate the key press entries that the IVR asks for. In short, if the IVR asks to press 1, the Amazon Connect should be automatically be able to send 1 as input.

As per my understanding, all the references suggest that we can get customer input and act on that, but my usecase is somewhat opposite.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the IVR from Amazon Connect? StartOutboundVoiceContact API? Dial from the agent desktop (CCP)? Quick connect? Transferring an existing call from within a contact flow? There are ways to send keypresses (DTMF is the terminology) from some of these methods but it depends on what you're doing.

For instance, the [transfer to phone number block](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/transfer-to-phone-number.html) has a 'Send DTMF' option that lets you send a series of keypresses. Note that this doesn't listen to the other IVR, it just sends the keys you define (you can use one or more `,` characters to add pauses; for example: `,,1,2,,,4`).

Comment: Yes, I am using the StartOutboundVoiceContact using boto3 python. I am not concerned about what IVR says, I just want to send series of digits during the call using AWS Python SDK. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate AWS Lex into the Contact Flow to handle the dialogue flow corresponding to the DTMF inputs. Since you're using boto3, you can use the `lexv2-runtime` client to handle the interactions.